# Recursive formula involving a piecewise function

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I am trying to construct a recursion, `g[t]`, where

- `g[t] = a[t]` if `g[t-1] = 1`
- `g[t] = b[t]` if `g[t-1] = 2`.

Additionally `a` and `b` are defined as:

```
a[t_] := If[0 <= RandomReal[] <= 0.94, 1, 2]
b[t_] := If[0 <= RandomReal[] <= 0.9, 2, 1]
```

So then I want (I've also tried it where I replace `a` and `b` with their original defintions):

```
g[t_]:= Piecewise[{{a[t], g[t - 1] = 1}, {b[t], g[t - 1] = 2}}]
g[1] = 1
```

This, however, is not working.

Comment: Welcome here. You are aware that `g[t-1]=1` does not mean *is equal to*? Therefore, you first two bullet points don't make sense to me, because after the *if* I expect a true/false.

Comment: My first two bullet points are not actually written into my code; I was just trying to give a general idea as to what I'm trying to do. The parts in boxes are what I'm actually working with. But do you mean that my conditions, g[t-1] = 1 or 2, defined in my piecewise function do not make sense? I've noticed that if i choose a simple condition, like t > 1, then my piecewise function works.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [18697](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18697/4330).

Comment: In my opinion, that one is indeed duplicate. However, maybe it is not too localized, as I guess this is a great place to learn for the first time the difference between `==` and `=`. I suggest we close this Q&A (but I'm still glad I got to write an answer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As halirutan has pointed out, the main problem with your code is the equals sign that in the second elements (conditions) of the lists in the list in the `Piecewise` function. This should be `==`.

The `t` in `a[t]` and `b[t]` suggests to me that you want to store values of these random sequences, rather than generating them over and over.

Also you can use `RandomChoice`, rather than your construction with `RandomReal`.

To store your values in the code below, I have used something that looks like a technique called memoization. For a and b, this changes the outcome, as things are generated only once, so it is not really memoization. But given a and b, calculating g from its stored previous value rather than going all the way back to t=1 is proper memoization. Note that in `g[t_]:=g[t]=body` the brackets should be read to be `g[t_]:= (g[t]=body)`. Search this site for memoization if you are not sure how it works :).

The code then becomes

```
ClearAll[a, b, g]
a[t_] := a[t] = RandomChoice[{0.94, 0.06} -> {1, 2}]
b[t_] := b[t] = RandomChoice[{0.9, 0.1} -> {1, 2}]
g[t_] := g[t] = 
  Piecewise[{{a[t], g[t - 1] == 1}, {b[t], g[t - 1] == 2}}]
g[1] = 1;
```

Note that more improvements can be made. For example, it is much faster to first generate say 100000 random variables all at once, than to generate them on the fly. But maybe that is something for a future question.

Comment: I did not search for duplicates, which I am sure there are. Do not hesitate to close this Q&A or whatever, do not let the presence of my answer or any upvotes for it discourage you to close/delete :P.

Answer (score 1):

I originally posted an incorrect post. This may have been better as a comment and does not address the code correct. However, I note that if the aim is a simulation, this  two state discrete Markov process staring in state 1 could be coded using Mathematica builtin functions:

```
markov = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, {{0.94, 0.06}, {0.1, 0.9}}]
```

Underlying graph:

```
el = EdgeList[Graph[markov]];
prop = PropertyValue[{Graph[markov], #}, "Probability"] & /@ el;
Graph[markov, EdgeLabels -> Thread[el -> prop], EdgeLabelStyle -> 12]
```

[image]

Random function (e.g 10 samples):

```
ranf=RandomFunction[markov,{0,10}]
```

This creates a TemporalData object

Do probability, probability in state 2 after 100 time steps

```
 Probability[x[100] == 1, x \[Distributed] markov]
```

(=0.625)

Compute Stationary Distribution:

```
stat = StationaryDistribution[markov];
```